# datetime64[ns] to timestamp unix (секунды)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, unixtimestamp

Есть датафрейм, в котором индекс это объект `DatetimeIndex`, он же формат даты `datetime64[ns]`

```
                       A  B  C
'2022-12-14 12:00:00'  1  2  3
'2022-12-14 12:00:01'  5  6  7
```

Необходимо из этого индекса сделать столбец `'timestamp_s'`, в котором собственно будет храниться время из индексов в формате `timestamp` `unix` секунды.

На ум пришло грубое решение:

```
df['timestamp_s'] = df.index.astype('int32')
df['timestamp_s'] = df['timestamp_s'].apply(lambda x: (x / 1000000000).__int__())
```

Собственно, сначала переводим `datetime64[ns]` в формат `int32`, ну и затем каждый элемент делим на 10000000, так как после конвертации у нас получились наносекунды. Интересует вопрос, думаю что есть дефолтная функция, которая сделает конвертацию гораздо быстрее, но как она выглядит?

p.s. Данное решение занимает ~53мс, датафрейм состоит из 2млн+ строк и 4 столбцов формата `int32`

Comment: не понятно, зачем вы используете apply.  `df['timestamp_s'] = df.index.view('int64')/(10**9)`

Comment: @strawdog, опыта мало, 3 день как изучаю пандус

Comment: @Ваше решение проделывает всю работу за 4мс, думаю результат лучше не сделать. Если хотите опубликуйте свой ответ, я его приму. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Вот, кстати, обратите внимание на этот кейс с apply - вся прелесть pandas (и, уверен, цель разработчиков) - в наличии векторизованных решений почти на все случаи жизни. так что, сначала ищите векторизованные решения, потом имплицитные циклы, потом уже "ванильные" питоновские.

Comment: @strawdog, ссылку в студию! - почитать-то  интересно что там за кейс!

Comment: Так вот он у вас перед глазами - скрытый цикл apply вместо векторного решения увеличивает время работы в 14 раз.

Comment: @ strawdog, думал вы ссылку хотели прикрепили на слове "этот", но забыли, не подумал что имеется ввиду мой вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, много времени отнимает имплицитный цикл `apply`, который здесь, кстати, не нужен:

```
df['timestamp_s'] = df.index.view('int64')/(10**9)
```

Обратите внимание на модификатор `.view()`, который теперь разработчики pandas рекомендуют использовать в подобных случаях вместо `.astype()`.